# Make AsyncTask inside fragment run after FragmentTransaction.commit()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

I have a `FragmentTransaction` in the activity, and I want the AsyncTask to run in the fragment after `fragmentTransaction.commit()`. How do I make `AsyncTask` run after `commit`? Because `AsyncTask` runs 2 times before and after the commit. Can anyone help?

*note: AsyncTask run with String of the activities that I sent using FragmentTransaction

Activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menudisplay);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        language = extras.getString("language");
        lang_id = extras.getInt("id");

        MyListFragment mylist = new MyListFragment();


        FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        mylist.language = language;
        fragmentTrans.add(mylist, "language");

        fragmentTrans.commit();
        Log.d("tes", "data loaded");

    }
```

Fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menulist_overview, container,
                false);
            System.out.println("tes="+language+" sama ini = "+asdf);
        onActivityCreated(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);


        return view;

    }
    public void onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        run();

    }

    public void run(){
        Log.d("Test","How many called?");
        if(language != null)
        new loadcat().execute();

    }
```

Comment: Please rephrase you question I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Could you post a particular code block that is giving you trouble.

Comment: @MikeD done. Do you understand what i mean? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the note you wrote but you can run the `AsyncTask` after you have `.commit()` the transaction simple by creating a public method inside of the fragment that executed you desired `AsyncTask` and to call it from the `Activity` at the desired point in code.

So for example if you crate this method inside the `Fragment`:

```
public void executeAsyncTask(String language, int lang_id)
{
     ...
     asyncTask.execute(language, lang_id);
}
```

And in Activity, you can call this method:

```
...
fragmentTrans.commit();
Log.d("tes", "data loaded");
mylist.executeAsyncTask(language,lang_id);
```

Comment: ERROR :Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{-----}: java.lang.NullPointerException. what does that mean?

Comment: It means that you are trying to access something that has no object or value content and it holds null.

Comment: Just now, i'm not using string from the activity. i create new String with value inside fragment and still call the method "executeAsyncTask()" from activity. Still error :(

Comment: If i call asynctask from oncreateview, it works. But its not what i want. I need to use parameter that specified at the beginning of activity. Can you help? Or maybe you need to see full code of fragment?

Comment: Lang_id is not use in fragment, its just for trace my code. :|

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `commit` execution callback is not exposed(or maybe even doesn't exist).

So the question is - when do you want to execute your `AsyncTask`?

If you want it to be executed once at the fragment creation, your code is right, except you should remove your explicit `onActivityCreated()` call from `onCreateView` like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menulist_overview, container,
            false);
        System.out.println("tes="+language+" sama ini = "+asdf);
    onActivityCreated(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); // REMOVE THIS LINE


    return view;

}
```

`onActivityCreated` is a callback. Calling it explicitly cause double execution of your task

Comment: oh sorry, it's just trial and error. I actually did not use it before